# How can I optimize this MySQL query to execute fastar?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, left-join

this is my query

```
SELECT * FROM ".TB_PREFIX."wdata 
left JOIN ".TB_PREFIX."vdata 
ON ".TB_PREFIX."vdata.wref = ".TB_PREFIX."wdata.id 
where ".TB_PREFIX."wdata.id = $id
```

and this is the result of slow query:

> Query_time: 0.005000  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 21184

How can I optimize this code to execute faster?

EDIT:

tables structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tss1_wdata` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fieldtype` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `oasistype` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `x` smallint(3) NOT NULL,
  `y` smallint(3) NOT NULL,
  `occupied` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `image` char(3) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `id_2` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=40402 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tss1_vdata` (
  `wref` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `owner` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` char(100) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `capital` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `pop` mediumint(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `cp` mediumint(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `celebration` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `wood` float(12,2) NOT NULL,
  `clay` float(12,2) NOT NULL,
  `iron` float(12,2) NOT NULL,
  `maxstore` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `crop` float(12,2) NOT NULL,
  `maxcrop` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `lastupdate` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `loyalty` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '100',
  `exp1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `exp2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `exp3` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `natar` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `starv` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `starvupdate` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`wref`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: please add CREATE statements for Wdata and vdata

Comment: @Marat i added it t edited part of my post

Comment: Query_time: 0.005000 it slow ??? its very fast :)

Comment: @echo_Me : yes but i have about 24 query same like this and its will be slow when users get higher , am i correct ?

Comment: i think your query is very fast , if you have 24  query then your problem is with managing or behandling them not the queries themself. or your script is slow.

Comment: your query is almost 0ms and they are very simple and nothing wrong , look your script or your code.

Comment: @echo_Me And i have confused because i use query in phpmyadmin and its says:  Showing rows 0 - 0 ( 1 total, Query took 0.0009 sec) but in the slow-log of mysql in the file its says something like this : SELECT * FROM tss1_wdata LEFT JOIN tss1_vdata ON tss1_vdata.wref = '20984' WHERE tss1_wdata.id = '20984' LIMIT 1;
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]  Id:    50
# Query_time: 0.005000  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 21176

Comment: yes its very fast . your are loading something or using big images or your script is slow. 0.00500 is 0 almost.

Comment: @echo_Me : very thanks alot for answers , i just thinking that 0.005 is high and slow and know i know that i must managing them for better performance

Comment: @Benjamin by the way, if you're making 24 queries at a time, SELECT * -blablabla- WHERE wdata.id IN (1,2,3,..etc); will be much faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a specific ID, so you can limit the result to 1 row. Also, you can replace wdata.id with the actual id in the ON statement.

```
SELECT * FROM ".TB_PREFIX."wdata
LEFT JOIN ".TB_PREFIX."vdata
ON ".TB_PREFIX."vdata.wref = '$id'
WHERE ".TB_PREFIX."wdata.id = '$id'
LIMIT 1
```

You have the right indices, so there's nothing to be done there.

Comment: thanks men , i use your edited query and the result is much better than the original query.. so the query is correct and optimized , right ? so i have to index the table for better performance ?

Comment: @Benjaminfox Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is pretty much meaningless.

Comment: It's not, actually, because after the engine has found 1 entry it just stops looking if you use `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: The tables have the right indices, so you can't optimize the query that way anymore. I think your query is fast already. Anything further seems like premature optimization.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have all necessary indexes and query itself is built just right, i.e. there is nothing to improve in SQL. Actually, I would not consider 5ms query as a slow one

If it is critical query executed thousands times a second, you still can cache result on application level or check NoSQL solution. I personally would try to cache it first.

Comment: very thanks for answer , im sry i have one question , there is one way i know about cache query. its apache modules . is there best way and easy way to cache querys ? tnx alot

Comment: caching means you just store result of SQL query at a faster storage, e.g. memcached php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php

Answer (score -1):

Try to avoid JOIN table, use short and simple query (single) and store results in php array or mysql memory, make sure all the conditions in mysql fields are indexed properly.

May refer mysqlperformanceblog.com for more mysql related articles.

Comment: tnx for reply, is there any tips or optimize for my query ? i will be grateful if the current query be optimize , sry for my bad english

Comment: "*try to avoid JOIN*" - that's what DBMS were built to do. A JOIN does not make a query necessarily slower.

Comment: @Benjaminfox actually optimization is not just limited to mysql query, but also the database and system I/O. Normally I'll do I/O performance or bandwidth test on a server first (SSD is good to have), then will use sysbench for mysql performance tuning, then the design of the table structure, then only query.

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/09/11/how-to-find-mysql-queries-worth-optimizing/